# Datagridview Combobox items is blank

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to use combobox in datagrid and all is ok. But when at run time the combobox seems to contain no data, this is my code:

```
Dim cbtn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim ls As New DataTable
    cbtn.Name = "Schedule"
    ls.Columns.Add("Day")
    ls.Rows.Add("Monday")
    ls.Rows.Add("Tuesday")
    ls.Rows.Add("Wednesday")
    ls.Rows.Add("Thursday")
    ls.Rows.Add("Friday")
    ls.Rows.Add("Saterday")
    cbtn.DataSource = ls
    cbtn.DisplayMember = "Day"
    DoctorDataView.Columns.Add(cbtn)
    cbtn.Width = DoctorDataView.Columns(DoctorDataView.Columns.Count - 1).Width / 2
```

I tried a list instead of data table, and even adding items directly gives no result!
Any help? (C# or VB code is ok)

Comment: Your code seems OK. Probably you are adding the column to a different `DataGridView` that the one you see. For example you may have a form reference problem (Changing a different form than the one you should change)

Comment: @RezaAghaei No, I can see the combobox in the DataGridView called "DoctorDataView" but once I click on it, no list is poped and the combobox seem to be empty from data!

Comment: Every thing with this code is OK. The problem is somewhere else. You should create a simple form containing a `DataGridView` and test it yourself and you will see there is no problem with this piece of code.

Comment: Ok, I will try this, and will see!

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ok, I did what you say and it worked. The real problem was that DoctorGridView ReadOnly property was set "True". When I turned it to false, the combobox poped the list normally and all is Ok. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

No data is shown for a row in the DataGridView with no value e.g. in the example below first row has a valid value, so does the third row. Second row is fine but shows no value while the last row has invalid data so we need to use assertion here.

Note I used DayNames to provide culture specific week day names where I usually use a custom namespace as in [this code example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Extending-My-Namespace-27fc6075).

Any ways hope this helps.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Public Class Form1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' One column added in the designer
    ''' Form load I add a ComboBox with weekday names for data source
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn With
            {
                .DataSource = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames,
                .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing,
                .Name = "DayColumn",
                .HeaderText = "Week day",
                .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            }
        )

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"AAA", "Friday"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"BBB"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"CCC", "Monday"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"DDD", "XYZ"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError

        If e.Exception.Message = "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid." Then
            Console.WriteLine("Not valid week name [{0}]", DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```